# Jquery-UI Sortable: How to tell if sorting was canceled in stop callback?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I set up a sortable with `stop` callback and binded `esc` to cancel current sorting. In `stop` callback, how can I tell if current sorting was canceled or completed?

Here is my current snippet:

```
this.$("tbody").sortable({
    start: function() {
        shortcut.add("esc", function() {
            that.$("tbody").sortable("cancel");
        });
    },
    handle: ".sortable-handle",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        shortcut.remove("esc");
        // how to check if cancel was called during sorting?
        if (!e.canceled) {
            // save new state 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the stop function try this.

```
stop: function(e, ui) {
    if(ui.item.sortable._isCanceled) {
        console.log('Sort action was canceled');
    } else {
        console.log('Sort action was not canceled');
    }
}
```